# bypassing secure boot on lenovo thinkpad s1

Tags: secure-boot

I have a second hand Lenovo yoga s1. I'm currently dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu on to but I want to run Kali on it instead of Ubuntu. the only problem is that kali doesn't have secure boot and the bios havs a password on it from the previous owner. is there any way of bypassing secure boot at all.

Answer (score 0):

Most computers provide a way to work around a firmware password. Typically, the procedure involves temporarily setting a jumper on the motherboard or holding the power key while the battery and power brick are unplugged. Check the manual (it's likely available online if you didn't get one) or call Lenovo for help with the details. If successful, this procedure will reset all the firmware settings to their defaults, including removing the firmware password. Thereafter, you should be able to enter the firmware and disable Secure Boot.

Of course, you could also ask whoever sold you the computer what the password is. (Maybe you haven't done this for a good reason, like if you got it from a thrift shop, which likely wouldn't know.)

Another option is to add Secure Boot support to Kali. I don't have a step-by-step procedure for doing this, but it basically involves adding the Shim EFI file to the boot medium, adding the MokManager binary to your boot medium, signing your boot loader/manager (GRUB, rEFInd, or whatever) with your own key, signing your kernel with your own key, and registering your key using MokManager (which Shim will launch when its follow-on program is refused by the firmware). Note that you'll have to do this with the USB drive you use for installation and most of it again after the OS is installed. This is admittedly a lot of hoop-jumping, but it *is* possible. [My Secure Boot page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) covers most of this in detail, but not in a step-by-step guide for your specific situation.

Another option is to keep using Ubuntu, or to switch to another distribution that explicitly supports Secure Boot. You can do anything with Ubuntu (or Fedora, OpenSUSE, or other distributions) that you can do with Kali -- it's "just" a matter of installing and configuring the right software. This may be anywhere from a trivial task of installing a few packages to a monumental one of completely revamping the installation's security model. Without knowing your reasons for wanting to use Kali, I can't say where this task might reside on the difficulty scale.